# How do I access a different users certificate store?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to install a certificate in a specific users certificate store while my application is running under a 2nd user.

Is there any way of getting this certificate store via the options that X509 provides or is there another method that anyone could suggest?

A constraint is I do not know the password to the user that I want to install the certificate on. The password routinely and randomly changes.

I also need to add that the user wanting to install the certificate has admin rights.

Comment: That would be a horrible security hole if you could do it.

Comment: I'm the administrator of the device and want to install a cert in personal store to allow them access to one of our internal encrypted sites.

Comment: Then why install it to the personal store and not the global device store?

Comment: As far as I was aware (but I'm fairly rookie at this) IE11 (which is installed on the devices) uses the current users personal store to select the certificates it can use for SSL